# Keep dynamic div rotator at same state across multiple pages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm planning to replace an old flash "cta" rotator with a jquery div rotator, there will be 3 divs each with 3 separate states.

the way the site used to work was with a main template page with all the content loading into an iframe to ensure the cta rotator was never interrupted on page load.

I was wondering what the best way to allow this div rotator to save animation states between pages would be.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its already a javascript rotator, you could benefit from the use of cookies.  Just have the rotator set the cookie's value on animation.  When you load the next page, use php to retrieve this cookie value and set the divs accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that would be along the lines of the way to go, was slightly hoping there was something less involved!